# CakePHP displaying "admi" at the top of any page

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to deal with some strange CakePHP behaviour. I enabled "admin" prefix in core.php and now I have "admi" at the top of any page...

```
admi<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

Literally out of nowhere, no trace of it in layout @ default.ctp.
Looks like some CakePHP bug, any ideas would be appreciated.

Running on localhost, Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.3.5, MySQL 5.1.63, Cake 2.o

Comment: check for any output in the action, `beforeFilter`, `beforeRender` and any other callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, "admi" was at the beginning of core.php, I probably added it accidentally when I was changing "admin prefix" there.